# How to store images(each grater than 20 mb ) in local storage as offline data when developing progressive web application?

Tags: php, reactjs, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

I am newbie in react.

I am developing a progressive web application. I am using local storage to store my data as offline. I want to capture and upload images which are more than 20 MB each in a size. I am not getting that how can i store those images within local storage and upload those when my app is online.

Comment: Please provide your code and describe in detail what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

With localStorage on mobile Devices I do not think this is doable. According to [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) Article you have 5-10MB of storage Data available. Taking in account that you only can store key value pairs (and therefore have do encode the image), I don't see how this could work.

But as far as I know PWA's can access the local file system. So why not store the images to the device and just keep the path in localStorage?